# What is the formal error of token bucket and can it be calibrated?

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a way to throttle the rate of a specific event. I have a hard limit on the number of events per second, but can tolerate some amount of error. The implementation needs to use as little memory as possible. We currently keep a queue of timestamps, which is always accurate, but it would be good to eliminate the memory footprint.

The token bucket algorithm seems like a good fit, but it only seems to guarantee an average rate. It can violate the limit depending on when the events happen relative to the token refill points.

How do I formulate the error of token bucket? Is it possible to calibrate it?

Answer (score 0):

In my first proposals you will have to store the algorithm start time and a counter, so just two values.

Make a fixed schedule.  Each event will be assigned a specific time which is derived directly by the algorithm's start time, the number of events since then, and the wanted rate:

`event_time = start_time + event_counter / rate`

After each event increase the `event_counter` and sleep until the `event_time` of the next event is due (`sleep(event_time - current_time)` or similar).

In my second proposal you will have to store a delay duration as well, so you will have three values to store.

After each event, sleep as long as the delay states and continue with the next event.  Also, after each event (or just if `counter % n == 0` to do it only after *n* events) you update the delay:  Using the current time, the start time and the counter you compute the current average rate; if it is too high, you increase the delay; if it is too low you decrease the delay; otherwise you leave the delay unchanged.

This automatically will work out an average delay needed for your kind of event and rate.  It will, however, have troubles staying smooth if your events vary much in duration.  In a worst case scenario (with a specific variation of durations) you might even get resonance effects of periodically rising and reducing delays.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You're basically implementing a control loop to regulate the rate of events to a steady flow, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. It's important for this application to allow short bursts and only let the limiting logic kick in when the upper limit is about to be breached.

Comment: That is correct.  But if your steady flow is normally significantly below the upper limit, the slept delay will just be 0 (i. e. no sleeping).  So applying my mechanism will just "kick in" when your events are too fast so that too many are handled and your rate increases too much.  Consider resetting my algorithm now and then (i. e. algorithm start time and event counter) to keep the regulatory short-timed.